# How to exclude '\' character from pwgen generated string?

Tags: linux, bash

I am using pwgen in bash script. I don't want backslash character ('\') in my newly generated password.

I know that we can use the -r option with pwgen to exclude unwanted characters something like -
`` pwgen -r \`\"\' ``

I wanted to clarify would the following command be good enough for excluding '\' from password generator -

```
pwgen -r \\\`\"\'
```

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: Where did you find the `-r` switch? At least it's not documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pwgen).

Comment: @tripleee I did try and it seems to be working, I just wanted to confirm thats why I asked

Comment: @user1934428 maybe it is present only in the newer versions, you can find it with the help of pwgen -h option

Comment: I don't have `pwgen` on my platform. It would help if you either provide a link to a web page describing your version of pwgen, or quote the respective part of your pwgen man-page in your question.